# iPhone browser continuously loads when using Signalr

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, signalr

I'm looking to develop a mobile web application allowing 2 people to talk to each other. To do this I'm using MVC3, jquery mobile and Signalr.

I have the basic functionality working on my machine, but when I test it on my iPhone the page shows as continually loading, I'm presuming this is due to Signalr?

Has anyone come across this and know how to rectify it or know of any other libraries like Signalr but meant for mobile devices?

Many thanks,
Mike

This is a link to a screenshot of my iphone: http://i1150.photobucket.com/albums/o618/mikeyb7fish/60c65836.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to delay the SignalR start-up like this: `setTimeout('$.connection.hub.start()', 2000);`

Comment: Doesnt seem to work for me unfortunately. Using SignalR 0.5.1

Comment: I discovered that the delay must be longer than it takes for the page to load. The basic rule appears to be - if the iPhone progress bar is still 'loading' when SignalR performs its connect, then the progress bar will not go away. The delay must be long enough so that the progress bar has hidden before SignalR connects. I am currently searching for an event that will let me determine this.

Comment: @Adam Put the timeout in page onload event + the delay. This way it will load on time

Comment: @RegisteredUser Yes, this is how I had it `$(function(){ window.settimeout....});` and it didnt work for my page.
The page onload will fire when all the HTML has loaded, ignoring the load state of images and any other ajax request. Hence, if your page is still loading either ajax requests, or images, when the signalR connect occurs, then your progress bar will never go away.

My point, is that its not enough to just use an arbitrary timeout from page-load, because the onload event does wait until EVEYRYTHING has loaded before firing - just HTML/js.

Answer (score 1):

SignalR may have fallen back to a [forever frame (hidden iframe)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) which makes some browsers appear to never finish loading the page. I have this problem as well with the project I'm working on but I haven't gotten around to figuring out how to fix it yet.  If it isn't something that you can configure in SignralR you might look to see if [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) has a polyfill that will do the trick.  It might be kind of hard to get any polyfill to play nice with SignalR's client side library though...

Answer (score 0):

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () { 
    $("#status").css('background-color', 'green').css('color', 'white').text('Ready'); 
}).fail(function () { 
    $("#status").css('background-color', 'red').css('color', 'white').text('Error connecting'); 
});


<div id="status" style="float: right; background-color: Yellow;">
    Connecting...
</div><i>
```